# How to use underlying generic types of generics C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have an internal generic method `byte[] catchAllOperation<T>(T genericItem)` and another one `byte[] arrayOperation<T>(T[] genericArray)`. Additionally, I have a highly specialized operation `byte[] specializedOperation<TKey,TValue>(CustomMap<Tkey,TValue> customMap)`.

How to write a method like this? (pseudocode):

```
public byte[] universalOperation<T>(T anything){
   if(T is CustomMap<UKey,UValue>){      // UKey/UValue are unknown
       return specializedOperation<UKey,UValue>(anything);
   } else if(T is U[]){                    // U is unknown
       return arrayOperation<U>(anything);
   }else{
       return catchAllOperation<T>(anything);
   }
}
```

How to get `U` and how to call `arrayOperation<U>(anything);` with `U` if I have only `T` (and the same for `CustomMap<>`)? Most questions I have seen assume that `U` is already known. Serializers use reflection to construct a separate method for each concrete type and then cache the method. But here I only want to redirect/dispatch a universal method to special cases when I could detect these cases.

I will have more types similar to `CustomMap`, so there is time to make any radical changes to code/approach. All special methods leverage the fact that for blittable underlying types some transformations and custom layout significantly boost the compression ratio of custom types. For custom types I could implement an interface, but for generic arrays it is not an option.

Comment: Is using Reflection an option here?

Comment: Yes, but for dispatching, not for building and caching the entire special methods. However, caching very small redirect methods built with reflection is OK.

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you're actually trying to do here but it smells like a misuse of generics.

Comment: Why don't you just add overloads to the `universalOperation()` method that handles those cases? Problem solved.

Comment: @AntP think of it as serialization, without building a delegate with reflection for each concrete type, but with redirecting to a special method for a certain generic "type shape"

Comment: Why do you use generics at all, why not just write specific overloads?

Comment: Actually I feel that I am doing something wrong and that is why I am asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question isn't *entirely* clear to me, but it sounds like you basically need to look in `typeof(T)` with reflection. Fortunately, dynamic typing in C# means you can get the compiler team to do the hard work - admittedly at execution time:

```
// Note: all names changed to be more conventional
public byte[] UniversalOperation<T>(T value)
{
    dynamic d = value;
    return DynamicOperation(d);
}

private byte[] DynamicOperation<UKey, UValue>(CustomMap<UKey, UValue> map)
{
    // Do stuff with the map here
}

private byte[] DynamicOperation<U>(U[] array)
{
    // Do something with the array here
}

private byte[] DynamicOperation(object value)
{
    // Fallback
}
```

Note that your `UniversalOperation` method doesn't have to be generic now - it will just use the execution-time type of the value. Of course, that means it may not be *quite* as you originally intended - for example, if the value is `null`, you're in trouble - whereas you could have potentially worked with `typeof(T)` despite that. Without knowing what you're trying to achieve, we can't tell whether or not that's a problem.

Comment: Thanks! Never thought about dynamic, testing this now.

Comment: Wow, this works? That's awesome. Is the overhead from the dynamic method resolution singificantly bigger than from a normal interface dispatch? Do I need to worry if I do something like this ten thousand times in a cycle?

Comment: @Luaan: That depends on how long your "cycle" is :) My experience with `dynamic` is that it's pretty fast - there's some nifty technology in there. It's not as fast as statically-bound dispatch, of course... but the OP would need to do work with reflection anyway, so it's not like static dispatch is an option.

Comment: I do not know how it is possible, but with `DynamicOperation` defined for all built-in primitives, a call via the `UniversalOperation<double>(value)` wrapper with dynamic is c.20% faster than direct calls to  `DynamicOperation(double value)` from another assembly (10M iterations). For nulls, I cache MethodInfo in a dictionary only for special cases, instead of everywhere (what DLR does automagically).  I now use this approach in many places and have rediscovered the power of dynamics due to this awesome answer!

Answer (score 1):

Like you are able to read comments it is not possible with generics. The only type is `T` do getting `U` and other types is not possible without reflection.
Sample solution:

```
public static void UniversalOperation<T>(T anything)
{
    // check for null etc.
    var anythingType = anything.GetType();

    if (anythingType.IsGenericType &&
          anythingType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(CustomMap<,>))
    {
        var genericArgs = anythingType.GetGenericArguments();
        var keyType = genericArgs[0];
        var valueType = genericArgs[1];

        return specializedOperation(keyValue, valueType, anything);
    }
    else if (anythingType.IsArray)
    {
        var elemType = anythingType.GetElementType();
        return arrayOperation(elemType, anything);
    }
    else
    {
        //T is parameter, so you can pass it
        catchAllOperation<T>(anything);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, solution above required non-generic version of `specializedOperation`. Anyway, most of serializes (did I understand corretly, you serialize it?) share with non-generic overloads.

Comment: Thanks! Changing generic to non-generic is trivial with typeof(T), so that is not a problem.